# why doesn't Session.Load<User>(id) return null if nothing was found?

Tags: nhibernate

When I try and load an entity by ID using:

```
Session.Load<User>(21);
```

I get a 'no row with the given identifier exists'.

In my code I was checking for null like:

```
if(user == null)
```

How am I suppose to know if the row didn't exist, or how can I make it return null instead?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because it doesn't actually make a round-trip to the database. You are actually getting back a proxy for lazy loading so NHibernate can't know if it really exists or not. If you need to know if really exists, you should use:

```
var entity = Session.Get(21)
```

Comment: I am doing that:  return Session.Load<T>(id);  oops, ok just read you wrote GET. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use `Get<T>(id)` ([more detailed explanation about NH get/load/query](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/04/30/nhibernate-ndash-the-difference-between-get-load-and-querying-by.aspx))